# The same script does not work in IE 11 (Office 365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, jquery

I have 98 libraries in one site (SharePoint online), and I did a script for exporting all libraries which have the same reference name to one page. This script works well in Chrome, but does not work in IE 11.
I have no idea.......

For example, I want to export all libraries that library name beginning with "DDD_"

```
<div>Library DDD :</div>
<ul id="DDDlist"></ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetLibrariesOnly, "sp.js");


function GetLibrariesOnly()
{
currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
currentweb = currentcontext.get_web();
this.listCollection = currentweb.get_lists();
currentcontext.load(listCollection,"Include(Title, DefaultViewUrl, BaseTemplate)");

currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.ExecuteOnSuccess),
Function.createDelegate(this, this.ExecuteOnFailure));
}

function ExecuteOnSuccess(sender, args) {
    //get id in HTML
     var DDDListTitle = document.getElementById("DDDlist");

var listEnumerator = this.listCollection.getEnumerator();

   while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) 
   {
            var list = listEnumerator.get_current();
            //get library name          
            var LibraryName = list.get_title();
            //get library default view url
            var URLshort = list.get_defaultViewUrl();       
            var URLlibrary = "https://domain"+URLshort; 

            if(list.get_baseTemplate() == '101' && LibraryName.includes("DDD_"))
            {               

             // Create a DIV to display the library name
                var answer = document.createElement("LI");

                var LinkLibray = document.createElement("A");   
                var TextLink = document.createTextNode(LibraryName);
                LinkLibray.title = LibraryName;
                LinkLibray.href = URLlibrary;
                LinkLibray.appendChild(TextLink);
                answer.appendChild(LinkLibray);                         

                //Add the library name to page
                DDDListTitle.appendChild(answer);

            }


   }

 }

function ExecuteOnFailure(sender, args) {
alert("Error in Getting Lists");
}


</script>
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? Or general erros in the console

Comment: @AndersAune, no error message, the page is blank in IE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(list.get_baseTemplate() == '101' && LibraryName.includes("DAF_"))
```

Check this link regarding the browser compatibility...IE does not support `includes`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Browser_compatibility